# Adobe AppMeasurement Library Changed

Tags: ios, adobe, analytics

I am using AppMesurement Library by Adobe for tracking my application. Recently when I was tring to convert my application to 64Bit Architecture I found that the Appmeasurement library is outdated. I tried searching the Adobe Site Catalyst to download the library but instead I found **ADBMobile** . Has Adobe changed the AppMeasurement Class and instead we have to implement the ADBMobile classes or there is still a repo where I can find the AppMeasurement file and libAppMeasurement.a file to support 64 BIT architecture.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking into this in anticipation of having to exactly the same upgrade that you're now working on.

I'm afraid I don't have a practical solution as I haven't actually started the upgrade yet, but I've been looking at this guide as a starting point to estimate the effort involved: https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/ios/migration_v3.html

Taking a look at the source code on GitHub it looks as though they have indeed changed the namespace of the files.

As painful as it's going to be for both of us to perform the upgrade, it's probably better to commit the time now and get the code up to the latest version, than to try to find an older version that reduces the effort.

**Edit**

I've done some more digging into their release notes. It looks like this change was made with the introduction of v4 of the SDK, which I understood to be the first version released with 64-bit support

Comment: Probably I dig in and found that ADOBE has changed the way the library behaved earlier, instead of creating pointers for each entity they now have direct methods to log the tracking. Surely we need to change the implementation by using ADBMobile class. Moreover this link helps you further https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/ios/